# Takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have this command that gives you information on a user. Problem is, I get an error when I use the command on another person. For example, `-userinfo` (gives you information on yourself) works perfectly, however, when I use `-userinfo @User1`(gives you information on another person) it will not give me their information.

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: userinfo_error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Code:

```
@userinfo.error
  async def userinfo_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
      embed = discord.Embed(color=3447003)
      embed.set_author(name = "Ubi", icon_url= embedIcon) 
      embed.add_field(
        name="Command On Cooldown!",value=f":timer: Try again in {error.retry_after:.2f} seconds!", 
      )
      embed.set_footer(
        text = embedFooter
      )
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)  
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
      embed = discord.Embed(color=3447003)
      embed.set_author(name = "Ubi", icon_url= embedIcon)
      embed.add_field(
        name="UserInfo Error!",value=":hash: The person you wanted information on is invalid! Try something like `-userinfo @User`", 
      )
      embed.set_footer(
        text = embedFooter
      )
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
      raise error
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: The error message has `userinfo_error()`, but the code has `userinfo()`.  What is the connection between these two functions, if any?

Comment: My mistake! Wrong piece of code... I just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this API, but I assume that you need to add a 3rd optional parameter to your `userinfo_error` function like you had with the previously posted `userinfo` function:

```
async def userinfo_error(ctx, error, user=None):
```